# django postagedb command refresh_from_db results in MemoryError or .DatabaseError: out of memory for query result

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks

I have an influencer object which have many to many field of 20K+ followers.

I can read up to 45 influencers one after the other and execute a worker on it followers.
It is not happening immediately but after few hours.

code:

```
while True:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=45) as executor:

        influencers = Influencer.objects.filter(
            status__in=[ProcessStatus.recorded, ProcessStatus.unfinished, ProcessStatus.in_progress]
        )

        # Process all the influencers.
        for influencer_obj in influencers:

            influencer_obj.refresh_from_db()

            # start the followers filtering process
            executor.submit(self.update, influencer_obj)
```

exception:

```
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    django.db.utils.DatabaseError: out of memory for query result
```

I do have a machine with 80GB running the client, while the postage db machine is not leaking memory (using free command).

First, where is the memory issue, on the client or on the db server?

Second, what can I do to avoid it ? should I release old obj ?

Answer (score 0):

I set DEBUG to FALSE.
This solved the issue, no more memory errors.
Django on debug saves every query to database, that may cause the error.

ref:
set DEBUG = False in your settings.py file.   If DEBUG is True, then Django saves a copy of every SQL statement it has executed. See Django FAQ: Why is Django leaking memory? (spoiler: Django’s not really leaking memory).

link:
https://travelingfrontiers.wordpress.com/2010/06/26/django-memory-error-how-to-work-with-large-databases/